# LMDE alongside Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, mint

I have previously installed Ubuntu 14.04 on its own,  but I would like to Dual-Boot Linux Mint Debian Edition alongside it, I thought I'd ask here, because Ubuntu is my 1st OS installed, and I would like to know the dangers. Also would Ubuntu and LMDE both show up when I boot the PC (So I can choose). Is there any tutorials on this?

Comment: I only suggest you install LMDE Grub on your partition /, and then from Ubuntu run sudo update-grub, to incorporate LMDE into de Ubuntu Grub menu, for dual boot.You should share swap. And you can share / home if is in separately partition, with different username .

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to follow the installation prompts of LMDE without hassle. Your bootloader might not be correctly installed if LMDE uses another older GRUB version. Then you will have to use a Ubuntu Live CD/USB with [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) (choose automatic mode).
If you already get a list of operating systems after installing LMDE, this step is not needed.

Always carefully look at your partitions, because otherwise you may overwrite your Ubuntu partition. Prepare your disk partitions before the installation of LMDE (from within a Ubuntu Live CD). For LMDE, you need at least one root partition (ext4 probably) and a swap partion (but since you have already installed Ubuntu, you can reuse that). Use GParted to create an extra root partion (resize your Ubuntu installation if you need space to create another partition)

You will have to try if LMDE live wants to dualboot, because I've seen scenarios where it did not want to install. If that's the case, you cannot install LMDE but Ubuntu is left untouched, fortunately.

Good luck.